# How can I added moblile table and desktop preview in site

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design

I use following code

```
<button class="md-primary">
<button class="md-primary">

<iframe src="{{LiveUrl}}"></iframe>
```

[image: moblie | Tablet | Desktop]

When clicking button should change inside iframe mobile or iframe

If not clear question, Pls comment here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-src` and change `LiveUrl`when click:

```
<button class="md-primary" ng-click="LiveUrl = 'theIframeUrl'">Desktop</button>
<button class="md-primary" ng-click="LiveUrl = 'theIframeMobileUrl'">Mobile</button>

<iframe ng-src="{{LiveUrl}}"></iframe>
```

Comment: But I need to change iframe properties or if can replace another tag for iframe. It's better.

Comment: What iframe attribute do you need to change?

Comment: I need to change like this site  quirktools.com/screenfly/ , When i click button it should preview mobile and desktop view.

Comment: play with `ng-class` and add/remove them when needed.